# form field label is displaying twice

Tags: symfony

I'm using macro to display a collection of videos in my form.

**Form**

```
{% import "macros/prototype.html.twig" as prototype %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form_row(form.title) }}
            {{ form_row(form.description) }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.videos) }}
                <div id="course_videos" class="collection_holder" data-prototype="{{ prototype.tagCollectionLinkItem(form.videos.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                    {% for video in form.videos.children %}
                        {{ prototype.tagCollectionLinkItem(video) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="add-video-btn" data-target-collection="#{{ form.videos.vars.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="la la-plus"></i> {{ 'course.buttons.add_video' | trans({}, 'labels') }}</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn m-btn--pill at-btn--primary pull-right" value="{{ button_name }}">
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Macro**

```
{% macro tagCollectionFileItem(item) %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div id="{{ item.vars.id }}">
    {% if item.uploadedFile.vars.file_url or item.uploadedFile.vars.image_url %}
        {{ form_errors(item.uploadedFile) }}
        {{ form_widget(item.uploadedFile, {'attr': {'hidden': true}}) }}
    {% else %}
        <div class="custom-file">
            {{ form_widget(item.uploadedFile) }}
            {{ form_label(item.uploadedFile, item.uploadedFile.vars.label, {'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-file-label'}}) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
</fieldset>
{% endmacro %}
```

`form_end` makes `form.videos` label to display twice. I guess because I never used `form_widget(form.videos)` so `form_end` makes it appears. Should I replace my macro with a form theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never rendered `form.video` with the widget you need to set the field as rendered. Just use `{{ do form.videos.setRendered }}` and you are good to go

Comment: I know that `setRendered` method but is that a good practice here??

Comment: @CyrilF I don’t see any reason why not

Comment: @CyrilF actually the other option is just to override the form theme for this field and use the form_widget

Comment: actually I needed to use `{% do... %}` instead of `{{ do... }}`